# single select vue js multiselect sub groups

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue js multiselect library for multiselect library. I am using the sub group functionality. 
. I want the functionality to allow only one option selection from one group. For example if I select vue js from javascript group, I shouldn't be allowed to select adonis for the given JS fiddle or else if I selelct vue js and then select adonis, then vue js should be deselected. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

**Example JS fiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/bgarrison25/tndsmkq1/4/

```js
new Vue({
 components: {
   Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
 },
 data () {
    return {
      options: [
        {
          language: 'Javascript',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Vue.js', category: 'Front-end' },
            { name: 'Adonis', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        },
        {
          language: 'Ruby',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Rails', category: 'Backend' },
            { name: 'Sinatra', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        },
        {
          language: 'Other',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Laravel', category: 'Backend' },
            { name: 'Phoenix', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        }
      ],
      value: [
        { name: 'Laravel', category: 'Backend' },
          { name: 'Phoenix', category: 'Backend' }
      ]
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.4/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.4/dist/vue-multiselect.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label class="typo__label">Groups</label>
  <multiselect 
    v-model="value" 
    :options="options" 
    :multiple="true" 
    group-values="libs" 
    group-label="language" 
    :group-select="true"
    placeholder="Type to search" 
    track-by="name" 
    label="name">
    <span slot="noResult">Oops! No elements found. Consider changing the search query.</span>
  </multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this below, it's a bit overly complicated for what it does, but could work well in its own component.

Basically on the input event you can search to see if there are any others in that group and then select accordingly.

```js
new Vue({
  components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
  },
  methods: {
    selectUnique(ev) {
      if (!ev || ev.length < this.value.length) {
        this.value = ev;
        return;
      }

      let newValue = ev.filter(x => this.value.indexOf(x) === -1)[0];
      let group = this.getGroupByLib(newValue);
      if (this.value.some(x => this.getGroupByLib(x) === group)) {
        this.value = this.value.filter(x => this.getGroupByLib(x) !== group);
        this.value.push(newValue);
      } else
        this.value = ev;
    },
    getGroupByLib(lib) {
      return this.options.filter(x => x.libs.some(y => y.name === lib.name))[0].language;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {

      options: [{
          language: 'Javascript',
          libs: [{
              name: 'Vue.js',
              category: 'Front-end'
            },
            {
              name: 'Adonis',
              category: 'Backend'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          language: 'Ruby',
          libs: [{
              name: 'Rails',
              category: 'Backend'
            },
            {
              name: 'Sinatra',
              category: 'Backend'
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          language: 'Other',
          libs: [{
              name: 'Laravel',
              category: 'Backend'
            },
            {
              name: 'Phoenix',
              category: 'Backend'
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      value: []
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Avenir', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css">
<div id="app">
  <label class="typo__label">Groups</label>
  <multiselect :value="value" :options="options" :multiple="true" group-values="libs" group-label="language" placeholder="Type to search" track-by="name" label="name" @input="selectUnique">
    <span slot="noResult">Oops! No elements found. Consider changing the search query.</span>
  </multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: It did worked , but the solution as you mentioned is bit overly complicated @Shoejep

Answer (score 0):

Make these two things into false

```html
 :multiple="false"  :group-select="false"
```

[Check Here Code](https://jsfiddle.net/xya0zftq/)